# What is Map.Entry<K,V> interface?

Tags: java, dictionary

I came across the following code :

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,VmAllocation> entry : allMap.entrySet()) {
       // ...
}
```

What does `Map.Entry<K,V>` mean ? What is the `entry` object ?

I read that the method `entrySet` returns a set view of the map. But I do not understand this initialization in `for-each` loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Map.Entry` is a key/value pair that forms one element of a `Map`. See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) for more details.

You typically would use this with:

```
Map<A, B> map = . . .;
for (Map.Entry<A, B> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    A key = entry.getKey();
    B value = entry.getValue();
}
```

If you need to process each key/value pair, this is more efficient than iterating over the key set and calling `get(key)` to get each value.

Comment: but `map.entrySet` returns a `Set`...I guess

Comment: I don't understand the equation like I understand this : `for(String s : listContainingStrings) {...}`

Comment: @saplingPro - Yes, it returns a `Set`. My code is using an _enhanced `for` loop_ (see [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) for more about that). It is shorthand for assigning the set to a variable and then looping through all the elements of the set with an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the docs: [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

`Map.Entry` is an object that represents one entry in a map.  (A standard map has 1 value for every 1 key.) So, this code will iterator over all key-value pairs.

You might print them out:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,VmAllocation> entry : allMap.entrySet()) {
       System.out.print("Key: " + entry.getKey());
       System.out.println(" / Value: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An entry is a key/value pair.  In this case, it is a mapping of `Integers` to `VmAllocation` objects.

As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) says

> A map entry (key-value pair). The Map.entrySet method returns a collection-view of the map, whose elements are of this class. The only way to obtain a reference to a map entry is from the iterator of this collection-view. These Map.Entry objects are valid only for the duration of the iteration; more formally, the behavior of a map entry is undefined if the backing map has been modified after the entry was returned by the iterator, except through the setValue operation on the map entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about [Map.Entry Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

> A map entry (key-value pair). The Map.entrySet method returns a collection-view of the map, whose elements are of this class. The only way to obtain a reference to a map entry is from the iterator of this collection-view. These Map.Entry objects are valid only for the duration of the iteration; more formally, the behavior of a map entry is undefined if the backing map has been modified after the entry was returned by the iterator, except through the setValue operation on the map entry.

Check [For Each Loop Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,VmAllocation> entry : allMap.entrySet())
```

`entry` is a variable of type `Map.Entry` which is instantiated with the `Entry` type data in `allMap` with each iteration.